# Resize Ubuntu partition using a non-adjacent Windows space

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning

Im using Ubunt 14.04 LTS. I have a dual boot (Windows 7 and Ubuntu. When I want to install upodates in Ubuntu I get the next messenge:

[error messenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYjyZ.png)

I really need more space in my Ubuntu partition.
This is the current partition-configuration:

[partition-configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPmvo.png)

I have not a live cd or usb right now.

I would like to reduce de size of the sda12 partition in about 10 GB and then use the space to increase in 10 GB the size of the sda4 (which I think is the partitition that I have to increase to solve the issue).

Would you please indicate me the step-by-step procedure to do this?

Regards,
Josè

Comment: you will need to use an offline partition tool to move the free space partition next to the partition you wish to expand, once done you should be able to expand it. the free space partition needs to be moved to the right (and right next to) of the partition you wish to expand.

Comment: If the partitions cannot be made adjacent, e.g. due to immovable files, then you can create an *additional* partition and use it for data storage, e.g. Documents, Video or Photo files. If NTFS, it could also be shared with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1) The key icon in the second column of the gparted image shows you booted from the drive you want to edit. You must boot from a drive other than the drive you wish to edit. Therefore, you must boot from a LiveUSB or LiveDVD to enable editing of partitions. Therefore, you must make or acquire one, since you do not have one now.

2) Changing partitions is the quickest, easiest way to permanently lose data. Make a complete backup to a drive outside your PC (or to the cloud) and then verify the backup just made matches the source files on your PC. Then, do it again, backing up to a different external drive or different cloud account, and verify that backup is accurate. Only then can you proceed with changes to partitions safely.

3) You may be able to resolve the issue by deleting kernels you don't use any more. Try that first.

4) sda4 can't be expanded until you shrink sda3 which requires you shrink partitions inside of sda3, e.g., sda12.

5) You must move sda4 towards the beginning of the drive and click the green checkmark to commit the change, before you can expand it with gparted.